# Rails redirect with html respond with js

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this question has been asked in different ways before, but in my case, I reviewed many answers and nothing seems to work. My case is simple:

I am making an api call to `https://www.facebook.com/v4.0/dialog/oauth?...` with a redirect to `/auth` which is a `GET`. It returns a code with which I am retrieving the access_token.

I added a `auth.js.erb` that should open a modal.

Very basic.

After storing the access_token, I want to redirect to the user profile and open up a modal with JS to show the user some more info.

For some reason my JS in respond_to never gets executed.

Here's my simple code:

```
def auth
    response = RestClient.post(
        "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/oauth/access_token",
        {
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            code: authorization_code,
            ...
        }
    )
    ...

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to edit_user_registration_path} # This works
        format.js # Never gets executed
    end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify the format in url. Tried this?

```
yoursite.com/auth.js
```

or

```
yoursite.com/auth?format=js
```

It might depend on your routes, and if you're accessing via browser url or ajax, etc.

Comment: Didn't work. format=js kept processing as HTML and .js resulted in RequestForgeryProtection. I'm just going to call the action in the redirected page html based on some conditions. Not ideal.